# Rails - Combining scopes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Here is the index method of my People Controller

```
def index
    @people_without_pagination = Person
        .for_branch(session[:branch_id])
        .for_interests(params[:interest_search])
        .search_query(params[:search_term])
        .for_lead_sources(params[:lead_source_search])
        .for_labels(params[:label_list_search])
    @people = Person
        .for_branch(session[:branch_id])
        .for_interests(params[:interest_search])
        .search_query(params[:search_term])
        .for_lead_sources(params[:lead_source_search])
        .for_labels(params[:label_list_search])
        .page params[:page] 
    if(params[:my_contacts]=="true")
        @people.my_contacts(current_user.id)
        @people_without_pagination.my_contacts(current_user.id)
    end
    get_facets
    @organization = Organization.find(session[:organization_id])
    respond_to do |format|
        format.html 
        format.json {render partial: 'table.html', locals: { people: @people, organization: @organization, facets: @facets}}
        format.csv { send_data @people_without_pagination.to_csv}
    end
end
```

As you can see, the my_contacts scope is only to be used when the param "my_contacts" is set to true.

However, it never seems to be applied when I split the scopes. When I combine the my_contacts scope with the rest, it works perfectly. Code here :

```
def index
    @people_without_pagination = Person
        .for_branch(session[:branch_id])
        .for_interests(params[:interest_search])
        .search_query(params[:search_term])
        .for_lead_sources(params[:lead_source_search])
        .for_labels(params[:label_list_search])
        .my_contacts(current_user.id)
    @people = Person
        .for_branch(session[:branch_id])
        .for_interests(params[:interest_search])
        .search_query(params[:search_term])
        .for_lead_sources(params[:lead_source_search])
        .for_labels(params[:label_list_search])
        .page(params[:page])
        .my_contacts(current_user.id)
    get_facets
    @organization = Organization.find(session[:organization_id])
    respond_to do |format|
        format.html 
        format.json {render partial: 'table.html', locals: { people: @people, organization: @organization, facets: @facets}}
        format.csv { send_data @people_without_pagination.to_csv}
    end
end
```

Is this not an acceptable way of combining scopes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each time you call the relation builder methods (`where`, `joins`, etc.) or your model's scopes you create a fresh new scope - it doesn't mutate the existing scope. So

```
@people.my_contacts(current_user.id)
```

Creates a new scope but then throws it away, leaving `@people` unchanged. You should be doing

```
@people = @people.my_contacts(current_user.id)
```

This also means that your code could be simpler:

```
@people_without_pagination = Person.
... #your scopes here
@people = @people_without_pagination.page(params[:page])
```

rather than repeating that list of scopes.